# IIS7 with MVC2 cannot load static resources

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, windows-7

my situation is:

- windows7
- visual studio 2010 (with mvc2)
- mvc2 web application compiled with .NET 3.5

I install IIS7 with StaticModule but when I try to load a css or an image I receive a blank page. Only html is loaded.

Help me please.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem on a server installation with IIS7 with a deployed ASP.NET application. Static css and images are not loaded. Images that are provided by resource request on a .NET server control are displayed correctly, but static images in th app path are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

did you open the page in firebug and is the file path, check if the file exists, and if your application does not ingore the path.
if you are using areas than you need to get full path to the files or create mapping.
or provide please more info..

oh yes , other problem is path in css file to image is not corect...
should solve